# Hide list items if more than a certain number exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
  <li class="children">6</li>
  <li class="children">7</li>
  <li class="children">8</li>
  <li class="children">9</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
  <li class="children">6</li>
  <li class="children">7</li>
  <li class="children">8</li>
  <li class="children">9</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
  <li class="children">6</li>
  <li class="children">7</li>
  <li class="children">8</li>
  <li class="children">9</li>
</ul>
```

What I would like is for / within each `<ul class="parent">`:

If count is: `3 > li <=6` hide the `<li>` above 3. If it is `6 > li <=9`, we hide the `<li>` above 6.

In fact, I have a row with elements. I *always* want to display 3 elements per row, but when there is less than 3 element on the last row, I want to hide this row completely.

Additionally, depending on the size of the browser (this seems to be easy), I want to change the factor number to 4 elements per row.

This does not seems to be possible in pure CSS, so I'm turning towards JS.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I see no javascript or any attempt to solve the problem.  You need to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Maybe do some research first on how to detect and set element width with javascript.

Comment: Hello,
I did try to find a solution myself, but I am a beginner in JS and posting some code here would be a non sense. This was the basic of a loop (foreach).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This does not seems to be possible in pure CSS

Challenge accepted.

The trick is to cascade `nth` counts, but only if it is `x` away from last child. Disclaimer, I kind of "cheated" to exclude some elements like `:not(:nth-child(5))`, but this comes at an advantage of not using things like `!important`

```css
.parent li:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(3):not(:nth-child(5)):not(:nth-child(6)) {
 display: none;
}
.parent li:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(-n+2):not(:nth-child(6)) {
 display: none;
}
.parent li:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(-n+1) {
 display: none;
}
.parent li:nth-child(n+7) {
 display: none;
}




/* just for styling */
body{ 
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

ul:before {
 content: "I started with " attr(data-count) " li's";
 background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent" data-count="3">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="parent" data-count="4">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent" data-count="5">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent" data-count="6">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
  <li class="children">6</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent" data-count="7">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
  <li class="children">6</li>
  <li class="children">7</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent" data-count="8">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
  <li class="children">6</li>
  <li class="children">7</li>
  <li class="children">8</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent" data-count="9">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
  <li class="children">6</li>
  <li class="children">7</li>
  <li class="children">8</li>
  <li class="children">9</li>
</ul>
```

By the way you asked way to many questions in the OP, so I elected to provide a solution to what I think is the priority of your question. You can adjust accordingly.

Comment: That is actually a pretty good solution. Very interesting but I need to understand the n+ side of it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @Séane the functions are already in plain english (`nth-child()` means a specific element at a position, `nth-last-child()` means an element, starting from the end) The hard part is targeting a specific order, I do agree there. If you look at css tricks they have more articles on how to do that. The tester you provided is great, but it doesn't cascade rules or concatenate them either. May I recommend a jsfiddle playground or something similar: https://jsfiddle.net/sgh7pqzj/1/ I am at work right now but if you need more info after that let me know and i'll update it as soon as I get a chance

Comment: :nth-child(n + 7) {
    display: none; } > hide all li elements after the 6th element, so 7 and more.

:nth-child(n + 4):nth-last-child(-n + 1) {
    display: none;  } > Hide the 1st li element of each series of 4 (3 + 1< hide the +1), so we only show 3

:nth-child(n + 4):nth-last-child(-n + 2):not(:nth-child(6)) {
    display: none; } > Hide the 2nd li element of each series of 5 (3 + 2 < hide +2), if it's not the 6th element of the list so we only show 3.

I am not getting the last one though. Or am I getting everything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Using Array#forEach and accessing the children of ul's you can do something like this.

```js
const uls = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("parent"));

const factor = 3;
const offset = 3;
uls.forEach(ul=>{
  const children = Array.from(ul.children);
  
  //if less than 3 hide everrything
  if(children.length < factor){
    children.forEach(li=>li.style.display = "none");
    return;
  }
 
  //default config to hide from 3 to 6
  let start = factor;
  let end   = factor + offset;
  //if length is greater than 6 and shorter than 9 hide those lis
  if(children.length > 6 && children.length <= 9){
    start = 6;
    end = 9;
  }
  
  children.slice(start, end).forEach(li=>li.style.display = "none");
  
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
  <li class="children">6</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
  <li class="children">6</li>
  <li class="children">7</li>
  <li class="children">8</li>
  <li class="children">9</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
  <li class="children">3</li>
  <li class="children">4</li>
  <li class="children">5</li>
  <li class="children">6</li>
  <li class="children">7</li>
  <li class="children">8</li>
  <li class="children">9</li>
  <li class="children">10</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="children">1</li>
  <li class="children">2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Many thanks.

It does the job and I will be able to fine tune if necessary.
But most of all I am learning a few things (such as the slice function).

Answer (score 1):

Based on @soulshined answer, I was able to do what I was looking for. Thank you all for your kind answers.

If width below 960, allow only 3 items per line, up to 6 items max. If on second line there is less than 6 items (and more than 3, first line), hide all of the items.

If width above 960, allow 4 items per line, up to 8 items max. If on second line there is less than 8 items (and more than 4, first line), hide all of the items.

Code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .product-sheet {
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 34px);
  }

  .product-list-tpl .product-sheet:nth-child(n + 7) {
    /* select all but the first 6 elements, allow 2 rows of 3 elements (3 X 2) and hide them */
    display: none;
  }

  .product-list-tpl
    .product-sheet:nth-child(n + 4):nth-last-child(-n
      + 2):not(:nth-child(5)):not(:nth-child(6)) {
    /* select all but the first 3 elements, so 4 and above and select the element before the last (last-1) of the list, so position 1 in second row / 4th item and hide it */
    background: red;
  }

  .product-list-tpl
    .product-sheet:nth-child(n + 4):nth-last-child(-n + 1):not(:nth-child(6)) {
    /* select all but the first 3 elements, so 4 and above and select the last element, so position 2 in second row / 5th item and hide it */
    background: purple;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .product-sheet {
    width: calc((100% / 4) - 34px);
  }

  .product-list-tpl .product-sheet:nth-child(n + 9) {
    /* select all but the first 8 elements, allow 2 rows of 4 elements (4 X 2) and hide them */
    display: none;
  }

  .product-list-tpl
    .product-sheet:nth-child(n + 5):nth-last-child(-n + 1):not(:nth-child(8)) {
    /* select all but the first 4 elements, so 5 and above and select the last element, so position 3 in second row / 7 th item and hide it */
    display: none;
  }

  .product-list-tpl
    .product-sheet:nth-child(n + 5):nth-last-child(-n
      + 2):not(:nth-child(7)):not(:nth-child(8)) {
    /* select all but the first 4 elements, so 5 and above and select the element before last element, so position 2 in second row / 6 th item and hide it */
    display: none;
  }

  .product-list-tpl
    .product-sheet:nth-child(n + 5):nth-last-child(-n
      + 3):not(:nth-child(6)):not(:nth-child(7)):not(:nth-child(8)) {
    /* select all but the first 4 elements, so 5 and above and select the last element, so position 1 in second row / 5 th item and hide it */
    display: none;
  }
}
```